# Check if workspace is used for the first time

Tags: eclipse, workspace

Is there any method to check if the currently used workspace is opened for the first time?

I made a startup plugin (IStartup) that opens the internal browser as an editor when my application starts but I only want to do this if the current workspace is used for the very first time.

I went through the methods of IResource, IWorkspace, etc.. but couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 0):

Store a preference in the workspace, or a hidden file under the workspace's on-disk location. Then check for it.